# Eclipse error adding web application to websphere liberty profile. Project facet Dynamic Web Module version 2.5 is not supported

Tags: eclipse, websphere-liberty

My teammate and I share a proyect. She uses Eclipse Mars 2.0 and web are trying to deploy our web proyect to Websphere Liberty profile v19. It does work in my laptop however she gets the below error whilst trying to add the app to the server:

```
Project facet Dynamic Web Module version 2.5 is not supported.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSphere Developer Tools for eclipse MARs are Archived / Out of support and really only support features up to Liberty V16.0.0.4 (see https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/websphere-developer-tools-releases/)... are you able to move to a version of WDT that supports Eclipse Oxygen (or later) and Liberty V19.0?

Comment: I can give a try. I'll let you know. 

Comment: I updated my colleague´s eclipse intallation to 2019_06 it worked smoothly. Thanks @Eric